# Kentor Auth services SAML 2.0 -Service certificate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kentor-authservices

AuthServices library for SAML 2.0  implementation in MVC application.I have provided all details from identity provider including meta data and SSO URl. But i am not able to understand what is Service certificate.What should i include here?Which certificate i have to add from App_Data folder?

Right now **Kentor.AuthServices.Tests.pfx** certificate is there. What should i replace instead of this certifcate.I am using **owin middleware authentication** from kentor.authservices library.
I have attached **app_start c#** code is below.

Thanks in advance.

```
var attributeConsumingService = new AttributeConsumingService("AuthServices")
        {
            IsDefault = true,
        };

        attributeConsumingService.RequestedAttributes.Add(
            new RequestedAttribute("urn:someName")
            {
                FriendlyName = "Some Name",
                IsRequired = true,
                NameFormat = RequestedAttribute.AttributeNameFormatUri
            });

        attributeConsumingService.RequestedAttributes.Add(
            new RequestedAttribute("Minimal"));

        spOptions.AttributeConsumingServices.Add(attributeConsumingService);

        spOptions.ServiceCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ApplicationBase + "/App_Data/Kentor.AuthServices.Tests.pfx", "", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet));

        return spOptions;
```

Comment: note that Service Certificate is only required if you are receiving encrypted assertions or signing outbound requests. If you are simply validating signed assertions from an Idp you only need to configure a certificate (or better yet, metadata) for each identity provider.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.It is very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @explunit said in a comment, you usually won't need a service certificate.

It is needed only if

- You are receiving encrypted assertions.
- The Idp requires AuthnRequests to be signed.
- You are using Single Logout (all logout messages must be signed).

In most simple setups it's not needed and can just be removed. Otherwise you can generate a self signed certificate and use that. There is generally no requirement in SAML2 that the certificate has a specific subject. I can even be expired and still work.